# ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt, root filesystem requires a manual fsck

Tags: boot, 22.04, filesystem, initramfs

I'm getting an error that's similar to many I've seen before, but I somehow can't seem to fix. I am on Ubuntu 22.04.

```
[    0.260527] ×86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.786997] Initramfs unpacking failed: ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt
/init: line 73: wait-for-root: not found
Finit: line 872: logsave: Text file busy
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck

BuSyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntus) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

At other times, I've only had to run something like...

```
fsck -fy /dev/sda2
```

... and error would get fixed and I'd be on my way.

However, this time around, I run the command I get:

```
(initramfs) fsck -fy /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2 e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, , blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda2: 908631/61022208 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 121159114/244059136 blocks

(initramfs)
```

Which seems fine. But then when I try to exit, I end up right back with it asking me to run a manual fsck check on the drive again. I have to force shutdown to get out of the shell (?).

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT:
I can use a live USB ubuntu session, and mount the disk without issues. I can see the files and open them without issue. So the drive is "fine" at least in some sense. SMART does not raise any warnings. So, why can't I boot with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This look like the `initramfs` image on your system is corrupted. Here is what you can do to regenerate the `initramfs` image:

1. boot on a live `Ubuntu` usb
2. mount your root partition `sudo mkdir /mnt` then `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
3. Mount the required file system

   `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev` then
   `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc` then
   `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
4. Chroot the mounted root partition `sudo chroot /mnt`
5. regen the `initramfs` image sudo `update-initramfs -u`
6. exit the terminal and `umount` the partitions exit
   `sudo umount /mnt/dev` then
   `sudo umount /mnt/proc` then
   `sudo umount /mnt/sys` the
   `sudo umount /mnt`

Then you can reboot, your system should work normaly

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, that fixed it. Learned something new today, too.