# Initramfs problem on booting

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem

I'm getting an error while booting ubuntu after a long time and need help in fixing it.

```
[1.506193] Initramfs unpacking failed: ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt 
/scripts/local-premount/resume:line 73: wait-for-root: not found 
/init: line 73: wait-for-root: not found
/init: line 872: logsave: not found
The root filesystem on /dev/sdb7 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

On running a manual fsck like this :-

```
(initramfs) fsck -fy /dev/sdb7
sh: fsck: Text file busy
(initramfs)
```

I get the following error:

```
ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt, root filesystem requires a manual fsck ; fsck: Text file busy
```

How am I supposed to solve this and boot into my ubuntu.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Might be a duplicate question for https://askubuntu.com/a/1461073/29073.

Comment: Yes this fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Yay, good for you, I'll report your question as a dupe.